# What is the recommended way to get tomcat-jdbc.jar on my classpath?

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, classpath

I'm running tomcat7 on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. Attaching to tomcat with jdb, here is my classpath:

```
> classpath
base directory: /var/lib/tomcat7
classpath: [/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar, /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar]
bootclasspath: [/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/resources.jar, /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/rt.jar, /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar, /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/jsse.jar, /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/jce.jar, /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/charsets.jar, /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/jfr.jar, /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/netx.jar, /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/plugin.jar, /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/rhino.jar, /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/classes
```

My problem is exactly this: [JDBC Cannot load Factory Class for Data Source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21286174/344286) it doesn't appear that `tomcat-jdbc.jar` is in my classpath. However:

me@mymachine /var/lib/tomcat7 ☭ ls server/classes | grep tomcat-jdbc                                                              9:00:12
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 124k Jun 12 16:39 tomcat-jdbc.jar

It's right there.

Why isn't this on my classpath, and more importantly how do I get it there?

Comment: Did you tried putting it inside lib folder of your tomcat: `apache-tomcat-6.0.32\lib`

Comment: I don't know how much help putting it in a tomcat6 folder will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `/var/lib/tomcat7/server/classes/*.jar` to `common.loader` in my `catalina.properties`  found at `/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/catalina.properties`.

This fixed that (and possibly others yet unseen) error